# C snprintf error

Tags: c, printf

Hello togheter.

```
const char* buffer = "";
printf("Creating Buffer..\n");
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "mkdir %s", argv[1]);
printf("Created, executing..\n");
system(buffer);
```

Why does this code above gave me this error?

```
Bus error: 10
```

Thanks for your answer

Dominic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line says:

1. Create a string with no characters (`= "";`).
2. Create a variable named buffer that points to this string (`char* buffer =`)
3. I promise that I don't modify that string via the variable (`const`).

And the next thing you do is to tell `snprintf()` to overwrite the string.
You also told `snprintf()` that the memory you have is the `sizeof()` the variable 'buffer'. But that is not true - the memory you have is the `sizeof()` the empty string `""`. The size of the variable that points to the string is different.

You promised to not overwrite the memory and even if you did not promise that, you only have memory for an empty string, not for a string that contains any characters.

Answer (score 0):

Bu error will come when you are accessing the bad memory. You are not having the memory for the pointer. You are using the mkdir command, so you can make a memory like this, for a single directory.

```
char buffer[265];// file length is 255, then mkdir and  a space.
```